# attrによって読み込むajaxを振り分けたい

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

下記の様なコードでボタン毎に読み込むjsonオブジェクトを切り替えて、画像を読み込みたいのですが、そもそもそういった事は可能でしょうか？

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('button').on('click', function(this){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'data-url.json',
      datatype: 'json',
      success: function(json) {
        $.each(json, function(i, activity) {
          var imgUrl = activity[i].img;
          $('#output1').append('<img src=' + imgUrl + '>');
        })
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log('error');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button data-attr="sports">Load More</button>
<button data-attr="workshop">Load More</button>
<button data-attr="culture">Load More</button>

<div id="output1"></div>
<div id="output2"></div>
<div id="output3"></div>
```

```js
[{
 "sports" : [
  {"name" : "soccer", "img" : "aaa.jpg"},
  {"name" : "baseball", "img" : "aaa.jpg"},
  {"name" : "tennis", "img" : "aaa.jpg"},
  {"name" : "swimming", "img" : "aaa.jpg"}
 ]
},
{
 "workshop" : [
  {"name" : "Traditional Craft", "img" : "bbb.jpg"},
  {"name" : "Ikebana", "img" : "bbb.jpg"},
  {"name" : "Washi", "img" : "bbb.jpg"},
  {"name" : "Miso Making", "img" : "bbb.jpg"}
 ]
},
{
 "culture" : [
  {"name" : "Zen", "img" : "ccc.jpg"},
  {"name" : "Ninja", "img" : "ccc.jpg"},
  {"name" : "Kimono", "img" : "ccc.jpg"},
  {"name" : "Cat Cafe", "img" : "ccc.jpg"}
 ]
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

質問に書かれたJSONの場合、各要素には次のようにしてアクセスできます。

```
[ // json
    { // json[0]
        "sports" : [ // json[0]["sports"]
            {"name" : "soccer", "img" : "aaa.jpg"}, // json[0]["sports"][0]
            {"name" : "baseball", "img" : "aaa.jpg"}, // json[0]["sports"][1]
            {"name" : "tennis", "img" : "aaa.jpg"},
            {"name" : "swimming", "img" : "aaa.jpg"}
        ]
    },
    { // json[1]
        "workshop" : [ // json[1]["workshop"]
...
```

この場合kotatsuさんの回答のように、配列を順番に見ないと `sports` や `workshop` にたどり着けません。代わりに次のようにしてはいかがでしょうか。

```
{ // json
    "sports" : [ // json["sports"]
        {"name" : "soccer", "img" : "aaa.jpg"}, // json["sports"][0]
        {"name" : "baseball", "img" : "aaa.jpg"}, // json["sports"][1]
        {"name" : "tennis", "img" : "aaa.jpg"},
        {"name" : "swimming", "img" : "aaa.jpg"}
    ],
    "workshop" : [ // json["workshop"]
        {"name" : "Traditional Craft", "img" : "bbb.jpg"}, //json["workshop"][0]
...
```

こうしておけば、以下のような流れで達成できるかと思います。

```
var activityType = $(this).attr('data-attr');

// jsonを取得してから、
var items = json[activityType];
$.each(items, function(i, item) {
    var imgUrl = item.img;
    ...
});
```

サンプル http://jsfiddle.net/njr793vd/3/

```js
var sample = {
  "sports": [{
      "name": "soccer",
      "img": "http://dummyimage.com/20x20/aaa/fff"
    },
    {
      "name": "baseball",
      "img": "aaa.jpg"
    },
    {
      "name": "tennis",
      "img": "aaa.jpg"
    },
    {
      "name": "swimming",
      "img": "aaa.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "workshop": [{
      "name": "Traditional Craft",
      "img": "http://dummyimage.com/20x20/afa/fff"
    },
    {
      "name": "Ikebana",
      "img": "bbb.jpg"
    },
    {
      "name": "Washi",
      "img": "bbb.jpg"
    },
    {
      "name": "Miso Making",
      "img": "bbb.jpg"
    }
  ],
  "culture": [{
      "name": "Zen",
      "img": "http://dummyimage.com/20x20/ffa/fff"
    },
    {
      "name": "Ninja",
      "img": "ccc.jpg"
    },
    {
      "name": "Kimono",
      "img": "ccc.jpg"
    },
    {
      "name": "Cat Cafe",
      "img": "ccc.jpg"
    }
  ]
};

$('button').on('click', function() {
  // 省略しましたが、引数にはEventオブジェクトが渡されます

  // この時点でthisはイベントを受け取った要素
  var activityType = $(this).attr('data-attr');

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/echo/json/',
    data: {
      json: JSON.stringify(sample)
    },
    // ここまでテスト用の設定

    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
      var items = json[activityType];

      $.each(items, function(i, item) {
        var imgUrl = item.img;

        // 多少効率は落ちますが、文字列連結ではなく
        // 要素生成して属性を設定したほうが安全です
        var img = $('<img>').attr('src', imgUrl);
        // もし文字列連結でやるなら、
        // src="..." のダブルクォートを忘れずに。

        $('#output1').append(img);
      })
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log('error');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-attr="sports">Load More</button>
<button data-attr="workshop">Load More</button>
<button data-attr="culture">Load More</button>

<div id="output1"></div>
```

Comment: すみません回答とは直接関係がないのですが、`/echo/json`で`ajax`のテストができるのですか？いい方法ですね。渡したデータが直接返される？

Comment: @kotatsu jsfiddleの機能ですね http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。これいいですね。スニペットでもできればいいですねえ･･･

Comment: 回答いただきましてありがとうございました。
こちらの想定していた通りの結果を出すことができまして、非常に助かりました。したがってこちらベストアンサーとさせていただきます。

Answer (score 1):

`append('<img src=' + imgUrl + '>')`での画像表示は可能です。
JSONデータの構造とアクセスの仕方が間違っています。

`getJsonData`は実行確認のためのダミーメソッドです。
実際は`success: function(json)`で取れるデータですので適宜読み替えてください。

画像のリンクは存在しないので`alt`属性の文字が表示されますが、正しい画像リンクであれば画像が表示されます。

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').on('click', function(){
        activityType = $(this).attr('data-attr');
        // JSONデータが取れた前提
        json = getJsonData()
        // success: function(json)内に書くロジック
        $.each(json, function(i, activity) {
            if(activityType != activity.type){
                return;
            }
            $.each(activity.list, function(j, list) {
                $('#output1').append('<img src="' + list.img + '" alt="' + list.name + '"><br />');
            });
        });
    });
});

// $.ajax()の代わり
function getJsonData(){
    return [
        {
            "type" : "sports",
            "list" : [
                {"name" : "soccer", "img" : "aaa.jpg"},
                {"name" : "baseball", "img" : "aaa.jpg"},
                {"name" : "tennis", "img" : "aaa.jpg"},
                {"name" : "swimming", "img" : "aaa.jpg"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "type" : "workshop",
            "list" : [
                {"name" : "Traditional Craft", "img" : "bbb.jpg"},
                {"name" : "Ikebana", "img" : "bbb.jpg"},
                {"name" : "Washi", "img" : "bbb.jpg"},
                {"name" : "Miso Making", "img" : "bbb.jpg"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "type" : "culture",
            "list" : [
                {"name" : "Zen", "img" : "ccc.jpg"},
                {"name" : "Ninja", "img" : "ccc.jpg"},
                {"name" : "Kimono", "img" : "ccc.jpg"},
                {"name" : "Cat Cafe", "img" : "ccc.jpg"}
            ]
        }
    ];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button data-attr="sports">Load More</button>
<button data-attr="workshop">Load More</button>
<button data-attr="culture">Load More</button>

<div id="output1"></div>
<div id="output2"></div>
<div id="output3"></div>
```